# Make JSON use POST requested instead of GET with ASP

Tags: json, asp-classic, google-translate

I'm using the Google Translator v2 service and this works great with small texts. For big texts Google gives a hint about sending a POST request instead of a GET. Which makes perfect sense. I just don't get how to do that. If I use the following code and replace 'GET' with 'POST' i'm still getting the error "414: URI too long". Can anyone help me understand how I can get the JSON function to work using POST, so I can request bigger texts?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2",
  data: { key: "<key>", source: FromLang, target: DestLang, q: Text },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function (data) {
    var ReturnedTextalert = data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
    setEditor(ReturnedTextalert, LongLang, DestField);
  },
  error: function (data) {
   alert('fail');
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that you force refreshed the page with the JavaScript?  Happened to me a few times that it did not load the updated script properly, even though the in browser editor showed that it was out of sync with what it actually loaded. CTRL+F5 solved it for me.

Comment: I've obviously tried that, tried it again. Cleared the cache etc. no effect. Error console gives me a 414, also saying that the "GET" is too long. Meaning eventhou i've put "POST" in the JSON function, it's still considered a "GET".

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I had the same problem with v1, but Google fixed it. I have been using the (free) Bing Translator and it seems to work every bit as well as the Google one, and does not seem to have the same 500 byte max. problem. Here's a jQuery plug-in I wrote using Google first and now Bing: jquery.bunkerhill.com.

Comment: In v1 I had a function that could repeat the call with a different chunks. I'd keep appending chunks of translated texts until the complete text was translated. That worked fine, it's just not that simple with JSON. I have tried to repeat the calls (even from within the "succes" in JSON, but Google kept only translating the latest call and not all my calls. If I get no solution for Google i'm going to try your Bing solution for sure! Thanks!